# Code cannot find my file

Tags: java, file

I have written a short program that will find a file I have made and print some of its details. It executes all right, but it cannot detect the file size or if it is hidden or not. E.G.

```
file path: C:\temp\filetext.txt last modified: 0 file size: 0 Is file hidden?false
```

The file does exist in the temp folder on C. I'm not really sure what the problem is

```
public void Q1()
{
    String fileName = "filetext.txt";
    getFileDetails(fileName);
}

public void getFileDetails(String fileName)
{
    String dirName = "C:/temp/";
    File productsFile = new File(dirName + fileName);
    long size = productsFile.length();
    System.out.println("file path: " + productsFile.getAbsolutePath() + " last modified: " + productsFile.lastModified() + " file size: " + productsFile.length() + " Is file hidden?" + productsFile.isHidden());
}
```

Comment: file path: C:\temp\filetext.txt last modified: 0 file size: 0 Is file hidden?false

Comment: It is saying the `File` is not hidden and has a size of `0`.  Are you saying the file **is** hidden and contains something?

Comment: I just ran it on my machine and it ran fine. It did print out what your seeing when the file didnt exist. Try adding 
    if(!productsFile.exists()) 
        System.out.println("This file doesnt exist"); in the getFileDetails to make sure your file can be found

Comment: I gpt the Same Ouput as Expected.. file path: C:\temp\filetext.txt last modified: 1367428266812 file size: 59 Is file hidden?false

Comment: Minor nit: better to do "new File(dirName, fileName);" and let the constructor combine the path components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File does not need a physical file to work with. Therefore your File object can exist even if the physical file it is supposed to represent does not exist/cannot be found. Check the JavaDoc for `length()` and `lastModified()`, they both return `0L` in case for example the file does not exist. So make sure your File objects is linked to an existing file on your file system by calling `file.exists()` before calling the other methods.

Comment: You're right about the file.exist, it doesn't seem to be able to find the file. But I did make a file named filetest.txt in the temp folder. I'm not really sure why it isn't picking it up. C:\temp

Comment: Well if you made a file named filetest.txt instead of filetext.txt as in your code, the problem is clear :-)

Comment: Show us the output from your program. I note that you used forward slashes in your path name; I don't know what happens on a Windows box when you do that in java. But yes, you should definitely check productsFile.exists() before you bother looking at any of the other properties.

Comment: Unfortunately that was just a typo. The file is called filetext in the temp folder. :-(

Comment: What you could also do in this simple case is just call `file.createNewFile()` and then search for the newly created file on your filesystem. That might give you a clue what's amiss here. Oh, and adhere to the advice posted in the comments of your thread by Edward Falk: try the `new File(dirName, fileName)` constructor.

Comment: Ahhh... you were right. I let the program make its own file if it couldn't find filetext.txt and figured it out. I made a dumb mistake and put the .txt filetype in the filename itself. It's working now so consider this case closed. Thanks to everyone who helped.